# R: Error in library(affy): Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘affy’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...): unable to load shared objec

Tags: r, r-package, bioconductor

```
>library(affy)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘affy’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/preprocessCore/libs/preprocessCore.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/preprocessCore/libs/preprocessCore.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: '/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/preprocessCore/libs/preprocessCore.so'
  Reason: tried: '/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file)
```

```
> library(BiocManager)
Bioconductor version 3.16 (BiocManager 1.30.19), R 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
> library('limma')
> library('GEOquery')
Loading required package: Biobase
Loading required package: BiocGenerics

Attaching package: ‘BiocGenerics’

The following object is masked from ‘package:limma’:

    plotMA

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    IQR, mad, sd, var, xtabs

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    anyDuplicated, aperm, append, as.data.frame, basename, cbind, colnames, dirname, do.call, duplicated,
    eval, evalq, Filter, Find, get, grep, grepl, intersect, is.unsorted, lapply, Map, mapply, match, mget,
    order, paste, pmax, pmax.int, pmin, pmin.int, Position, rank, rbind, Reduce, rownames, sapply, setdiff,
    sort, table, tapply, union, unique, unsplit, which.max, which.min

Welcome to Bioconductor

    Vignettes contain introductory material; view with 'browseVignettes()'. To cite Bioconductor, see
    'citation("Biobase")', and for packages 'citation("pkgname")'.

Setting options('download.file.method.GEOquery'='auto')
Setting options('GEOquery.inmemory.gpl'=FALSE)
```

Mac M2 R 4.2.2
what I have been adjusted:
1\I've been opened /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library and deleted the folder 'affy', then reinstalled it. But the error still presented here.
By the way, it was successful to library 'Bio conductor', 'limma', and 'GEO query'?
2\After that, I checked that all packages are up to date.
3\ Package 'haven' also were installed successfully.

so what is the problem of 'library(affy)'? how can I fix it? Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: the installation as follows:
> BiocManager::install(c("affy"))
.......
The downloaded binary packages are in
 /var/folders/m0/gzd3m7rd51b4ps80h9nkdr480000gn/T//Rtmpon8mln/downloaded_packages

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after updating to R 4.2.2. For some reason, gfortan was missing.
I installed the tarball from this link: https://mac.r-project.org/tools/ and run the command:

`export PATH=$PATH:/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/bin`
`sudo tar fxz gfortran-12.0.1-20220312-is-darwin20-arm64.tar.xz -C /`

and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a few errors like this, reporting as fortran install problems on macs, resolved by reinstalling xcode.

[Reset your Xcode Install on macOS](https://gist.github.com/Justintime50/2349ff5e62555aa097acbf519bbc27af)

Comment: *If* Xcode is installed at all, which it usually shouldn’t be, unless you’re using it for application development (it’s a *huge*, and unnecessary, installation package). But I guess the same would be true for the command line tools: reinstalling those should fix this as well.